# RosAria node rosaria package not working after installation

Tags: rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I installed ROSARIA as per tutorial given in [link text](http://wiki.ros.org/ROSARIA/Tutorials/How%20to%20use%20ROSARIA) .. I faced few issues when certain packages conflicted during installation. I solved them and installed it. But now I dont find rosaria package being listed in rospack list and also I am not able to run the RosAria node.. also there is no directory rosaria in /opt/ros/share .. please help out!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/199952/rosaria-node-rosaria-package-not-working-after-installation/) by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) on ROS Answers with karma: 88 on 2014-12-22

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2014-12-23**:
Please post any errors you received building rosaria to https://github.com/amor-ros-pkg/rosaria/issues, or you can send them to me.

**Comment by [ReedHedges](https://answers.ros.org/users/422/reedhedges/) on 2014-12-23**:
After cloning from git then building, it will be in your catkin workspace. You can run it from there with rosrun.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey thanks for the help. btw i solved the problem. i explicitly added my catkin workspace path to bashrc even after sourcing setup.bash in ~/catkin_ws/devel . i had an error even after that. i copied the binary to ~/catkin_ws/install/share and thereafter there was not any problem. this was unusual. but i dont know how it solved the problem.

---

Originally posted by [gaussian](https://answers.ros.org/users/21014/gaussian/) with karma: 88 on 2014-12-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0